# pycurl и curl запрос по протоколу https: pycurl.error: server certificate verification failed

Tags: python, curl, ssl

Хочу сделать запрос к апи сайта при помощи pycurl.

Пример рабочего запроса из командной строки.

```
curl -k "https://192.168.2.1/api/login?username=admin&password=admin"
```

код на питоне

```
buffer = BytesIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://192.168.2.1/api/login?username=admin&password=admin')
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
c.close()

body = buffer.getvalue()
# Body is a byte string.
# We have to know the encoding in order to print it to a text file
# such as standard output.
print(body.decode("iso-8859-1"))
```

выдает ошибку

```
pycurl.error, (60, 'server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none')
```

Вопрос в том как заставить аналогичный запрос работать на python.

[`curl` команда без `-k` опции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785153/pycurl-%d0%b8-curl-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83-https-pycurl-error-server-certificate-verifi#comment1233853_785179):

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate

[`urlopen(url, context=ssl.create_default_context())`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785153/pycurl-%d0%b8-curl-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83-https-pycurl-error-server-certificate-verifi#comment1233887_785179) исключение вызывает:

```
urllib.error.URLError, <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)>
```

Comment: А urllib/requests вас чем не устроили? Зачем pycurl?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я newbee в питоне, мне сказали  лучше делать через pycurl. Для меня не принципиально.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов , но все равно хочется понять в чем моя проблема сейчас.

Comment: Русским по белому же написано: не может PyCURL сертификат проверить. Вероятно, нет сертификатов в хранилище, которым пользуется PyCURL

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов окей, а где его взять и как положить?

Comment: В душе не представляю, потому что вы используете экзотику типа PyCURL

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ага спасибо,  а вы можете написать пример 
https запроса на urllib/requests ?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов pycurl может быть полезен для людей из других языков в Питон пришедших (curl очень переносим), чтобы не учить новое API. Более идиоматичное и рекомендуемое решение для Питона это requests модуль (если специфичных потребностей нет).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> server certificate verification failed  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Сообщение об ошибке говорит, что согласно информации в указанном CAfile, присланный с данного сайта сертификат не проходит проверку.

Для сравнения, с yandex сайтом тот же код без проблем работает:

```
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://ya.ru')
c.perform()
```

Команда `curl -k` у вас работает так как ключ `-k` (`--insecure`) выключает проверку, что *позволяет третьим лицами подслушивать/изменять сообщения от/к сайту* (делает соединение уязвимым к [MITM атаке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)). Ожидаемо [просто `curl <url>` ошибку возвращает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785153/pycurl-%d0%b8-curl-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83-https#comment1233853_785179):

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate

IP частный в вопросе указан, попросите у администратора сайта сертификат, который можно в `curl --cacert` опцию передать. Если у вас нет возможности получить сертификат напрямую, то чтобы не использовать небезопасное соединение при каждом соединении, вы можете один раз скачать сертификат:

```
$ openssl s_client -prexit -servername $host -connect $host:443 </dev/null | openssl x509 >server.crt
```

где `host=192.168.2.1`.

Если предположить, что соединение не было скомпрометировано когда вы `server.crt` получали, то после этого можно безопасно запрашивать url:

```
$ curl --cacert server.crt https://$host/path?query
```

или в Питоне:

```
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, url)
c.setopt(c.CAINFO, 'server.crt')
c.perform()
```

или используя `requests` модуль:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(url, verify='server.crt')
print(r.text)
```

или используя urllib из стандартной библиотеки:

```
import ssl
import urllib.request

context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile='server.crt')
with urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=context) as r:
    print(r.read().decode(r.headers.get_content_charset('utf-8')))
```

Проверка сертификатов включена по умолчанию начиная с [Python 2.7.9](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-476-enabling-certificate-verification-by-default-for-stdlib-http-clients) и [Python 3.4.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#changed-in-3-4-3).

---

Чтобы выключить проверку сертификатов (**не рекомендуется**) для pycurl:

```
c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)  # default 1
c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)  # default 2
```

для `requests` модуля, чтобы выключить защиту, можно передать `verify=False`.

Чтобы открыть себя к [MITM атаке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) при использовании стандартной библиотеки: `urlopen(url, context=ssl._create_stdlib_context())`.

Answer (score 0):

Пример с urllib2. Лучше как минимум тем, что не нужен дополнительный пакет, да и кода меньше:

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen("https://ya.ru")
print f.read()
```

Comment: спасибо, адаптировал ваш код под питон 3

Comment: это также на современных версиях Python 2.7 не будет работать, так как включена проверка сертификатов по умолчанию.

Comment: @jfs на 2.7.6 работает.

Comment: @jfs 2.7.13 тоже работает

Comment: @SkiF оно "работает" для yandex потому что у него по цепочке сертификат валидный. У автора в вопросе, не yandex, а другой сайт. Прочтите сообщение об ошибке в вопросе (английского не знаете, то хоть в любой переводчик засуньте). Что вы думаете -k опция делает у curl? Для чего c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0) существует?

Comment: @jfs с этим исплавлением вылетает ошибка  pycurl.error, (51, "SSL: certificate subject name (ocg.example.com) does not match target host name '192.168.2.1'")

Comment: @SkiF: это уже другая ошибка (`c.SSL_VERIFYHOST` опция ответственна). Не нужно пытаться выключить проверку сертификатов, наоборот, следует добавить проверку корректную. [c.CAINFO путь выставите.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13072667/4279)

Comment: @SkiF к примеру, [для сервера c самоподписанным `server.crt`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/780290/23044) путь к этому файлу в CAINFO укажите

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий код на python 3

```
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen('https://192.168.2.1/api/login?username=admin&password=admin')
print (f.read())
```

Comment: какая у вас версия Питона 3? Это не должно работать на современных версиях Питона, где проверяются по умолчанию сертификаты. `curl -k` работает потому это выключает проверку сертификатов. Полное название опции `--insecure`. Без проверки, MITM атака возможна.

Comment: @jfs версия питона 3.4.3

Comment: на версии 3.4.3 может быть включена проверка (pep-476). Правильно я понимаю `curl <url>` команда с ошибкой завершается (60 возвращаемый код), а `curl -k <url>` работает для вас? Что происходит если код в ответе запустить?

Comment: curl -k возращает правильный джесон как и этот код.

Comment: а без -k опции?

Comment: @jfs curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate

Comment: это ожидаемо. Что будет, если в urlopen передать явно  `context=ssl.create_default_context()` аргумент ? (после `import ssl`)

Comment: @jfs а куда это надо добавить? context=ssl.create_default_context()

Comment: в urlopen() которую я явно упомянул в комментарии и которую вы в ответе используете.

Comment: context=ssl.create_default_context() 
urllib.request.urlopen('https://192.168.2.1/api/login?username=admin&password=admin,context)

Comment: нет, по имени как я показал следует передавать. Внутрь скобок поместите: `urlopen(url, context=ssl.create_default_context())`

Comment: @jfs urllib.error.URLError, <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)>

Comment: отлично.  Значит у вас установка Питона не совсем сломана. На современных версиях Питона как раз `context=ssl.create_default_context()` по умолчанию и используется. Я проверил на моей машине и [согласно документации](https://goo.gl/KHqhED) на Питоне 3.4.3 этот контекст, а не `ssl._create_stdlib_context()` используется.¶ Стоит отметить, что если код в ответе у вас "работает", а с `context=...` вы получаете `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED`, то кто-то поменял вашу инсталяцию Питона таким образом, что можно подслушивать/изменять https запросы (как `curl --insecure`). Исправьте