# Получить чистый текст без тегов с HTML страницы обязательно используя CURL из python

Tags: html, python, парсер

помогите, пожалуйста, получить чистый текст без тегов.
Никогда не занимался парсингом.
пытался это реализовать вот таким образом, получаю на выходе только лишь теги

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)"
p = Popen(["curl", '-k', url], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
text, err = p.communicate()
out = str(text, 'utf-8', 'ignore')
print(out)
```

Comment: да, нужно использовать именно CURL, такое требование.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Strip HTML from strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/753052/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить содержимое Wikipedia страницы без разметки, можно использовать [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page):

```
$ curl 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext&titles=Java_%28programming_language%29' | 
  jq -r '.. | .extract? | select(. != null)'
```

[Basic jq usage. How to get nested value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41712363/4279).

На Питоне:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
from urllib.parse import quote as urlquote
from urllib.request import urlopen

title = 'Java (programming language)'
url = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
       "?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext"
       "&titles=" + urlquote(title))
with urlopen(url) as response:
    data = json.loads(response.read().decode())
    for page in data['query']['pages'].values():
        print(page['extract'])
```

Если есть желание вызвать `curl` команду прямо из Питона:

```
import subprocess

json_text = subprocess.check_output(['curl', url], encoding='utf-8')
```

См. [Перенаправление вывода терминала в переменную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/728672/23044). Можно pycurl библиотеку использовать: [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/785253/23044).

В более общем случае, если нет у сайта явного или неявного (подсмотренного) API, то curl, который может только вернуть ответ http-сервера, не сможет текст без html разметки вернуть. curl команда это не браузер и в частности не является html-парсером или javascript интерпретатором. То есть curl никак не поможет, если содержимое генерируется на лету в javascript или с разбором полученной html разметки. В этом другие инструменты могут помочь: [Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749943/23044)

Наивные regex могут легко сломаться при разборе html: [Is ">" (U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN) allowed inside an html-element attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/94528/4279)

Удобно текст из html выбрать, используя [beautifulsoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import bs4  # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.get_text())
```

В реальных примерах, стоит исключить содержимое `<script>`, `<style>` элементов.  Есть специализированные инструменты для чистки html, к примеру, 
[`lxml.html.clean`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#cleaning-up-html).

Стоит различать удаление всей разметки из html документа и получение текста, который можно безопасно вставить в другой html документ.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import os
req = os.popen("curl 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)' | sed 's/<\/*[^>]*>//g' ").read()
print(req)
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. Попробовал. Вывод такой: The specified path is invalid.

Comment: только что попробовал еще раз, работает:

Comment: сейчас допишу вывод

Comment: `>>> import os

>>> req = os.popen("curl 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)' | sed 's/<\/*[^>]*>//g' ").read()
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  289k  100  289k    0     0   312k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  312k

>>> req
'\n\n\n\nJava (programming language) - Wikipedia
`

Comment: нет нужды regex для разбора html использовать (это не будет работать в общем случае, а в частном случае можно попросить нужное содержимое через API вернуть).